# wrong output while printing prime numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, primes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[100]; 
    int n=0,m=1,k=0,g=0;
    for(n=0;n<100;n++) //1
    {
        a[n]=m;
        m=m+1;
    }
    int b[50]={2,3}; //2
    g=2;

    for(n=3;n<100;n++) //3
    {
        for(k=0;k<g;k++) //4
        {
            if(a[n]%b[k]==0) //5
                break;
            else if(k=g-1)  //6
            {
                b[g]=a[n];
                g=g+1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("the prime nos are \n");
    for(m=0;m<50;m++) //7
    {
        printf("%d \n ",b[m]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this program I have to print prime numbers between 1 to 100. The method told to follow was - to find out prime, divide a number by previous prime numbers stored in an array. If the given number leaves 0 as remainder while dividing by any of previous primes, then it is not a prime. If not, it is a prime and add that to the array.
IN THE PROGRAM - I initialized an array of 100 numbers and stores 1 to 100 numbers in an array a (step 1). `b`  is the array I will store primes. I stored first two values of `b` in (step 2). In (step 3) I initialize array `a` to check for primes. In (step 4) I initialize array `b` to divide array `a` elements. In (step 5) I put condition that if a number gives 0 as remainder then break out of loop and check for next number. In (step 6) I put condition that when a number is not divisible by previous primes and check if we have divided it by the last prime no in array, if condition is true then it is prime and we increment accordingly. In (step 7) I'm printing all elements of array `b`.

The output is not coming as primes, instead it listed all odd numbers. Where was I wrong and how to code it keeping logic intact.

Comment: For starters, help yourself and others by using best practices to make your code readable. Use consistent indentation. Use meaningful variable names and not just single letters. A few well placed comments wouldn't hurt either. After doing that, run your program in a debugger and step through it line by line - better to learn the tools for finding problems yourself rather than having someone else do it for you.

Comment: `(k=g-1)` should be `(k==g-1)`. NB The number of primes in `b[]` is not 50, it is `g`.

Comment: @user207421 got correct answer thanks!

Comment: @kaylum I'll keep your inputs in mind while asking question . I'll also learn to use a debugger.

Comment: regarding: `for(n=0;n<100;n++) //1
    {
        a[n]=m;
        m=m+1;
    }`  the value `1` is, by definition, not a prime number.  Here is the definition of a prime number:  *A prime number is a whole number **greater than 1** whose only factors are 1 and itself. *

Answer (score 2):

Change `k=g-1` to `k==g-1`.

This is because, in C, we use `==` to check if two expressions are equal.